# How to read to asio buffer say `1` byte from one socket and than `read_some` more from another?

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio, keep-alive

So I am trying to implement timed http connection Keep-Alive. And I need to be capable of killing it on some time-out. So currently I have (or at least I would like to have):

```
void http_request::timed_receive_base(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket, int buffer_size, int seconds_to_wait, int seconds_to_parse)
{
    this->clear();

    http_request_parser_state parser_state = METHOD;

    char* buffer = new char[buffer_size];
    std::string key = "";
    std::string value = "";
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.rdbuf()->assign( boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), socket.native() );
    try
    {
        do
        {
            stream.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(seconds_to_wait));
            int bytes_read = stream.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, buffer_size));
            stream.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(seconds_to_parse));
            if (stream) // false if read timed out or other error
            {
                parse_buffer(buffer, parser_state, key, value, bytes_read);
            }
            else
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Waiting for 2 long...");
            }


        } while (parser_state != OK);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        delete buffer;
        throw;
    }
    delete buffer;
}
```

But there is no read_some in tcp::iostream, so compiler gives me an error:

```
Error   1   error C2039: 'read_some' : is not a member of 'boost::asio::basic_socket_iostream<Protocol>'
```

That is why I wonder - how to read 1 byte via `stream.read` (like `stream.read(buffer, 1);`) and than `read_some` to that very buffer via socket API (  it would look like `int bytes_read = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, buffer_size));` and than call my `parse_buffer` function with real `bytes_read` value)

BTW it seems like there will be a really sad problem of 1 last byte..(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be a bit rough, but did you read the documentation? The socket iostream is supposed to work like the normal iostream, like `cin` and `cout`. Just do `stream >> var`. Maybe you want `basic_stream_socket::read_some` instead?